# Python script that checks if values in an array are less than 24 and appends them to a list

Tags: python, list, append

I need to write a script in python that does the following :

Creates an empty list

Uses a for loop to check if any value in an array is below 24.75

If that value is less than 24.75, it should append that value into an empty list.

```
#Create a variable to hold the list 
list = []


for i in [0,len(array)]:
#Use if statement to check if each value is less than 24.75
    if i < 24.75:
        
        list.append(i)

print(list)
```

and i keep getting [0], even though there are values that would make the if statement true.

Comment: Don't use Python built-in `list` as the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

You're using:

```
for i in [0,len(array)]:
```

But you want to use

```
for i in array:
```

As written, your code is iterating over the two elements `0` and whatever the length of `array` is.